# Hijacking node require

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I do this

```
const originalRequire = _.cloneDeep(require);
require = function(arg) {
    if (isSpecialArgument(arg)) {
        doSpecialInclusion(arg);
    } else {
        originalRequire(arg);
    }
};
```

Would I be losing the caching support of `require`? If so how else can I hijack require?